# RegTest Genesis Error

Tags: blockchain, hash, genesis-block

how to generate regression test genesis block ? i saw in bitcion nonce is 2. but i generate from
GenesisH0 it not showed nonce 2. for other altcoin i saw nonce is 0 why ? how to generate it ?

python genesis.py -a scrypt -z "xxxxxx." -t xxxxxxx -v xxxxx -p "xxxxxxxxx" -n 0

Here is my error when run compile file.

chainparams.cpp:319: CRegTestParams::CRegTestParams(const ArgsManager&): Assertion `consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x060696d44c5aeca64530875d13f349aa5436ce8a55087af86d9e7684c25fedf5")' failed.

Here is example of other reg test hash genesis:

```
genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1296688602, 0, 0x207fffff, 1, 50 * COIN);
    consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
    assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x530827f38f93b43ed12af0b3ad25a288dc02ed74d6d7857862df51fc56c416f9"));
    assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x97ddfbbae6be97fd6cdf3e7ca13232a3afff2353e29badfab7f73011edd4ced9"));
```

please help to advice how to generate reg test genesis?